# laravel auth::attempt() always return false

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I tried to create a login system but Auth::attempt always return false even though I entered the correct data. I have hashed the password when registering. Here's my code

**LoginController**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index()
    {
        return view('login.index', [
            "title" => "Login",
            "active" => "login",
        ]);
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email:dns',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        // dd(Auth::attempt($credentials));

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
        }

        return back()->with('loginError', 'These credentials do not match our records.');
    }
}
```

Comment: If I have to give my answer with personal experience. May be you hashed it double!

Comment: I checked and I didn't hashed it double

Comment: Did you get loginError message or nothing? I want to ensure that validation part is success or failed.

Comment: yes I get the error message as I wrote there 'These credentials do not match our records.' and it stays on the login page

Answer (score 0):

Did you hashed the password using `bcrypt($password)` helper method or `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::make($password)` class method ?

Or,

May be there is another code for hashing in `Model`, `Controller`, `Scope`, `Event`, `Listener`, `Observer`, etc. file. Please check  every file which is recently created and related to `User` Model.

Read more about hashing, if you need docs: [Hashing](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/hashing)

Comment: yes i have used Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash; in RegisterController

Comment: @01gurl try to use `bcrypt` when you are creating users